# Condense two seperate arrays into one

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter, cross-reference

The two scripts are working as intended, it basically takes a column of strings, filters certain phrases and then using .offset it renames a cell's contents. In  this case the script looks at a list of *Phones* and *Tablets* and looks for things like *4G*, *5G*, and *Cell* to determine the difference.

Only problem is that there's two columns I need to perform the check on the same row, if column G matches true and column P matches false, there's a confict and it messes up the accuracy of the returned data. Which ever script runs last overwrites the .offset and has last say.

Data is stored to this variable:
arrResult

My intention is to merge the same script under one, check both G and P together, then filter them out under the same arrResult.

```
Sub FilterOut()

'Under column G, look for all ipads and samsungs that don't have 4g, 5g, and cell and name them Tablets
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Full Asset List")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr(): Dim arrResult()
Dim rg As Range: Dim i As Long

Set rg = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow)
arr = Application.Transpose(rg)

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(arr(i), "SAMSUNG TABLET") <> 0 Or InStr(arr(i), "IPAD") <> 0 Or InStr(arr(i), "ipad") <> 0 Then
        If InStr(arr(i), "64GB") <> 0 Then arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "64GB", "!@!")
            If InStr(arr(i), "*CELL*") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "*cell*") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "4G") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "5G") = 0 Then
                If InStr(arr(i), "!@!") <> 0 Then arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "!@!", "64GB")
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To j)
                arrResult(j) = arr(i)
            End If
    End If
Next i

With rg
    .AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:=arrResult, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -2).Value = "Tablet"
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -3).Value = "Tablet"
End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

```
Sub FilterOut2()

'Under column P, look for all ipads and samsungs that don't have 4g, 5g, and cell and name them Tablets
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Full Asset List")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Range("P" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr(): Dim arrResult()
Dim rg As Range: Dim i As Long

Set rg = ws.Range("P1:P" & lastRow)
arr = Application.Transpose(rg)

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(arr(i), "IPAD") <> 0 Or InStr(arr(i), "ipad") <> 0 Then
        If InStr(arr(i), "64GB") <> 0 Then arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "64GB", "!@!")
            If InStr(arr(i), "CELL") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "cell") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "4G") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "5G") = 0 Then
                If InStr(arr(i), "!@!") <> 0 Then arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "!@!", "64GB")
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To j)
                arrResult(j) = arr(i)
            End If
    End If
Next i

With rg
    .AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:=arrResult, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -11).Value = "Tablet"
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -12).Value = "Tablet"
End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

I have tried to select two ranges but autofilter doesn't like that, I tried to run the whole script under a loop for each column but again the problem of having last say shows up.

**Edit**
Here's my attempt at changing:

```
Error: Object Variable or with block variable not set

.AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:=arrResult, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

```
Sub FilterOut3()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Full Asset List")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Range("P" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr(): Dim arrResult()
Dim rg As Range: Dim i As Long

arr = ws.Range("G1:P" & lastRow).Value

'arr = Application.Transpose(rg)

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(arr(i, 1), "IPAD") <> 0 Or InStr(arr(i, 1), "ipad") <> 0 Then
        If InStr(arr(i, 1), "64GB") <> 0 Then arr(i, 1) = Replace(arr(i, 1), "64GB", "!@!")
            If InStr(arr(i, 1), "CELL") = 0 And InStr(arr(i, 1), "cell") = 0 And InStr(arr(i, 1), "4G") = 0 And InStr(arr(i, 1), "5G") = 0 Then
                If InStr(arr(i, 1), "!@!") <> 0 Then arr(i, 1) = Replace(arr(i, 1), "!@!", "64GB")
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To j)
                arrResult(j) = arr(i, 1)
            End If
    End If
Next i

With rg
    .AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:=arrResult, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -11).Value = "Tablet"
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -12).Value = "Tablet"
End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have two columns which contain essentially the same data.

Comment: Its just a csv file provided from another team at work that I'm automating, do you have a solution? Thanks

Comment: Yes, tell the other team to get their act together and consolidate the two columns before passing on to you.  If they can't do that then you should do the consolidation before filtering.  This might be a simple as just concatenating the text from the two cells as it appears you only need one hit.  If it needs to be more complex then you'll need to explain the rules that will apply.  Presenting a sample of your data may help.

Comment: I cannot understand why you work with 1D arrays. You can use a 2D array obtained as `arr = ws.Range("G1:P" & lastRow).Value`. Supposing that both columns have the same number of rows. If not, you should choose the larger one. And check both involved columns.

Comment: @freeflow I know it doesn't make sense, but I'm just working with the tools I'm given. I'm not going to change a whole way of working just because I personally don't like it for scripting reasons. The report is generated by upper management and has been for years. Column P is for "Notes", Instead of putting 4G in G, they leave notes sometimes if its a tablet or not. Frustrating but I can't do anything about it.

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried that but I didn't get anywhere. I'm essentially reverse engineering the code since I didn't write it, Once I change the code I get subscript out of range.

Comment: That, probably, because you try working as you do in 1D arrays. You should try something like `If InStr(arr(i, 1), "SAMSUNG TABLET") <> 0 Or ...` (for G:G column, then before the `End If` you should try `ElseIf InStr(arr(i, 10), "IPAD") <> 0 Or ...` for P:P column (the tenth in the range G:P).

Comment: If you are afraid of changing the code, you can differently name the two arrays and one of them (the first) do be globally declared. Then, in the second code, before the filtering you can merge the two arrays. I can supply a simple function able do do it, if needed.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have tried to modify this myself but I am getting stuck. I appreciate the help so far though. I was hoping at the bare minumum I could increase the range but just pull column G or P again and that would get me started, but I'm now getting errors elseswhere now. - Included my attempt above.

Comment: Then, forget above solving the issue in a single loop. I will post a function able to merge the two arrays and use it just before the filtering...

Comment: your attempt was very close, change `With rg` to `With ws.Range("G1:P" & lastRow)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below combines both codes, I also simplified the `If` structure a lot
and removed the "64GB" replacement because it's not achieving anything.

```
Sub FilterOut_Combined()

'Look for all ipads and samsungs that don't have 4g, 5g, and cell in column P or G and name them Tablets

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Full Asset List")
Dim lastRow As Long, lRow2 As Long
lastRow = ws.Range("P" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
If lRow2 > lastRow Then lastRow = lRow2 'use whichever is bigger

Dim arrP(), arrG(), arrResult()
Dim rgP As Range, rgG as Range, i As Long

Set rgP = ws.Range("P1:P" & lastRow): Set rgG = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow)
arrP = Application.Transpose(rgP): arrG = Application.Transpose(rgG)

For i = LBound(arrP) To UBound(arrP)
    If (LCase(arrP(i)) Like "*ipad*" Or LCase(arrG(i)) Like "*ipad*") And _
        Not (LCase(arrP(i)) Like "*cell*" Or LCase(arrG(i)) Like "*cell*" Or arrP(i) Like "*4G*" Or arrG(i) Like "*4G*" Or arrP(i) Like "*5G*" Or arrG(i) Like "*5G*") _
        Then
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 to j)
            arrResult(j) = arrP(i) ' just using P for the filtering
    End If
Next i

With rgP
    .AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:=arrResult, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -11).Value = "Tablet"
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -12).Value = "Tablet"
End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Mate, Couldn't thank you enough, I'd tip you if I could. I can now see where I wen't wrong and understand it now!

Comment: @TomTK well I've just realised a potential bug - need to add brackets before the `And` within the loop. Editing now

Answer (score 1):

Please, try using the next function able to merge two (1D) arrays (1 based), as your question was about:

```
Function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) As Variant
   Dim i As Long, k As Long
   Dim arr: arr = arr1: k = 1
   ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr1) + UBound(arr2))
   
   For i = UBound(arr1) + 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = arr2(k): k = k + 1
   Next i
   mergeArrays = arr
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testMergeArrays()
   Dim arrResult1, arrResult
    arrResult1 = Application.Transpose(Range("F2:F10").Value)
    arrResult = Application.Transpose(Range("I2:I6").Value)
   arrResult = mergeArrays(arrResult1, arrResult)
   
   'only to visualy see the result (Immediate Window - Ctrl + G):
   Debug.Print Join(arrResult, "|")
End Sub
```

In order to use it in your environment, you should proceed in the next way:

1. Declare the first array on top of the standard module where the used code exists:

```
   Public arrResult1
```

And use it instead of `arrResult` of your first code.

2. Keep the second code as it is and insert the next line just above (existing) `With rg`:

```
   arrResult = mergeArrays(arrResult1, arrResult)
```